# nvd3.js - unable to change color of symbol in scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, scatter-plot, color-scheme

I am trying to change the colors of different groups of the nvd3 scatter chart [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav) but am unable to understand how to do so. I would like to change the colors of the 4 series in the example to orange, green, yellow, red.

```
    nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
    .showDistX(true)
    .showDistY(true)
    .color( d3.scale.category10().range() ); //  tried to change to green, orange here but it did not work 
    };
```

I tried

```
        .color( d3.rgb("green"), d3.rgb("orange") );
```

but then the plot did not even appear. I am new to javascript. So please excuse my mistake if it is too simple.

**Edit**

I also would like to know how to choose the color based on RGB values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color function takes an array of colours. For the scatter plot this equates to one colour per data group.

if you change it to

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
.showDistX(true)
.showDistY(true)
.color(  [d3.rgb("green"), d3.rgb("orange")] ); 
};
```

it seems to work as you need.

**EDIT - setting colour using RGB string**

this can be done using css syntax

```
 nv.addGraph(function() {
chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
.showDistX(true)
.showDistY(true)
.color(  ["rgb(0,255,0)","rgb(255,165,0)"] ); 
};
```

You would do well to read the API documentation at https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/API-Documentation

Comment: Can we specify the RGB values instead of `green` or `orange`?

Comment: you can use css syntax

Comment: Could you answer this question - I am facing a similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993992/nvd3-js-unable-to-change-color-of-line-in-line-chart