# nvd3.js - unable to change color of line in line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, color-scheme, linechart

I am trying to change the colors of different lines of the nvd3 line chart [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav) but am unable to understand how to do so. I would like to change the colors of the 2 lines in the example to green and cyan. I tried

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
   var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
      .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
      .color(["rgb(0,255,0)","rgb(255,165,0)"]);
}
```

It worked for scatter chart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992707/nvd3-js-unable-to-change-color-of-symbol-in-scatter-plot#22992996). But the color does not change for line chart. Any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work in this case because the color for the lines is specified in the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this!

```
return [
    {
      values: data,      //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
      key: 'Money', //key  - the name of the series.
      color: '#33ccff'  //color - optional: choose your own line color.
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 4):

In your CSS:

```
.nv-group.nv-series-0 {
    stroke-opacity: 1; 
    fill-opacity: 0.5; 
    fill: red; 
    stroke: red;
}
```

This will change the color for the first line to red, for example. Use `.nv-group.nv-series-1` for second line, and so on...

Comment: Are there custom colors based on rgb values defined too?

Comment: You pretty much can define any color you want, say, `fill: rgb(0,255,0)` or `stroke: rgb(0,255,0)` for green, etc.

Comment: Didn't work for me without adding `!important`s. Also, it (obviously) doesn't change the colour of related components, e.g. the legend.